# Why is umask changeing

Tags: tcsh, umask

Problem:  umask changes when new shell is created, despite what's in .cshrc

On linux... In my .cshrc, I have "umask 002"
At the prompt I see 2...

```
% umask
2
```

I have a shell script...

```
#! /usr/bin/env tcsh

echo "umask in shell: "
umask

exit;
```

Then I run it...

```
% a.csh
umask in shell:
22
```

Why isn't this just 2 ? Why did it change to 22?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OpenBSD with `tcsh` 6.20.00.

Comment: Run `strace -f /path/to/your/tcsh-script` and search for a call to `umask`, then search backward to see which file was recently opened. Might be /etc/cshrc, or /etc/csh.cshrc.